# Event not defined error, only in firefox

Tags: javascript, events, keydown, onkeydown

I have a code below which tells you which keys you pressed, when you type in the textarea, and it works in Google Chrome. However, in Firefox, when you pressed a key, there is a event not defined error. How would we fix this?

```
<textarea onkeydown = "checkKey()"></textarea>

<script>

function checkKey() {

var key = event.keyCode;
alert(key);

} //end of checkKey()

</script>
```

**P.S:**  I don't want jQuery solutions. Pure JavaScript only. Unless we can't do it in pure JavaScript. Then I'll accept jQuery solutions.

Comment: You're using non-standard global `event` object. `event` object has to be passed in FF, and maybe in some other browsers too. Adding events using `addEventListener` would be preferred, it works in all modern browsers.

Comment: I would *highly* suggest using `.addEventListener` instead of inline events.

Comment: `function checkKey(event) { ... }`...

Comment: @MarcB What if checkKey has more than 0 parameters already?

Comment: jQuery is a library written in pure javascript, anything jQuery does is just a shortcut/convenience method wrapper for a function that javascript can already do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`event` is defined in chrome, but not in firefox. You can do pass event as an argument.

```
<textarea onkeydown = "checkKey(event)"></textarea>

<script>

function checkKey(event) {

var key = event.keyCode;
alert(key);

} //end of checkKey()

</script>
```

Comment: Do we just add event to the parameter anyways?

Comment: Keep `event` as the first argument in `checkKey(event, arg1, arg2)`